# How to prevent back flow for parallel connected tanks?

Tags: plumbing

Two parallel over head water tanks are connected at the same height and have the output pipes connected to a single pipe into the home. How can back flow of water from tank to tank be prevented?

Comment: Use a non-return valve?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it, isn't it done that way by design?

Comment: The pipe dia from the tank is 3/4 inch , non-return valve will available in th emarket?

Comment: Oh all right, I'll make an answer from my comment ...

Comment: With backflow preventer? LOL

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [non-return valve](http://www.wickes.co.uk/3-4in-PVC-Non-Return-Valve-FI-BSP-1061/p/227371)

[image]

> Diameter: 0.75 in
>   Maximum Bar Pressure: 16 bar
>   Type: Non-Return
>   Colour: Black-Grey
>   Material: PVC
>
> Ideally used for conveying water and other fluids in urban and inter-urban infrastructure, industrial, mining, landscape, and farming applications

Note: This one seems expensive, I suspect I can buy about ten [22mm metal-bodied double-check valves](http://www.wickes.co.uk/22mm-Double-Check-Valve/p/221384) for this price.

The secret to buying plumbing parts is to specify *exactly* what sort of pipe you are joining, materials, nominal and actual diameters, joining method, types of fluids and pressures to be carried and so on.

It is disappointing when you find your 40mm push-fit spigot won't fit into your 40mm "Multifit" compression coupling, or you find that your spare parts box has 40mm ABS solvent-weld elbows but only 40mm  MUPVC solvent-weld pipe (and your PVC-only solvent has jelled anyway). Find a local plumbing supplies outlet and try to build up a good relationship with them so you can get advice and can return parts that don't fit the way you expected.

Comment: In case you don't know what it is or how it works, a non-return valve (or "check valve" in the states, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_valve ) only allows flow travel in one direction. They utilize various methods to accomplish this: spring loaded ball, weighted diaphragm, swinging disc, etc.